# Matrix Differentiation

Tags: derivatives, self-learning

Consider a differentiable function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and two $p\times 1$ vectors $x$ and $\theta$. Then define a new function as follows.
$$
f\left( x^T\theta \right)x.
$$
Now we want to find the derivative of the new function with respect to $\theta$.
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}f\left( x^T\theta \right)x = f'\left( x^T\theta \right) \frac{d}{d\theta}\left( x^T\theta \right) x = f'\left( x^T\theta \right)  x x.
$$
So $f'\left( x^T\theta \right)$ is a scalar. $\frac{d}{d\theta}\left( x^T\theta \right)$ should a column vector. However, this clearly is not right since it does not make sense to have $xx$. The correct answer is $xx^T$. However, I cannot see why this should be the case. Is this some kind of convention? Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean to take the derivative of a function with respect to a vector?

Comment: @muaddib Just a column vector whose entry is the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t. each entry of the vector. Right?

Comment: $f(x^T \theta)x$ is vector valued. Thus, it is derivative is a matrix, not a vector in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this systematically as follows.

Use the Chain Rule together with the fact that the derivative of a linear transformation $A$ is itself. Define the linear transformations: 
$$\varphi_x\colon\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R},\ \varphi_x(\theta) = x^T\theta$$
$$\psi_x\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^p,\ \psi_x(y) = xy$$
Then, your function is $g(\theta) = (\psi_x\circ f\circ \varphi_x)(\theta)$ with derivative
\begin{align}
g'(\theta) 
&= \psi_x'(f(x^T\theta)) \cdot f'(x^T\theta) \cdot \varphi_x'(\theta) \\
&= x \cdot f'(x^T\theta) \cdot x^T \\
&= f'(x^T\theta) xx^T
\end{align}

Comment: Do you mean $y$ is a scalar? Then $xy$ is the same as $yx$. But the order seems to make some difference here. By your definition, we have $g(\theta) = xf(x^T\theta)$.

Comment: Yes, $y$ is a scalar and $xy = yx$, but we still prefer to write $xy$ here.
The order is important to make sure everything makes sense and that it represents actual matrix multiplication.

Comment: $xy$ has matrix factors of size $(p\times 1)\cdot (1\times 1)$, which gives a product of size $p\times 1$.  The other ordering $yx$ is $(1\times 1)\cdot (p\times 1)$ which is not valid matrix multiplication. Using $yx$ would just make things confusing.

Comment: I see the point now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean by $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ the Jacobian.

For a function $\phi:\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R$ notice that 
$$\frac{d}{d\theta} [\phi(\theta) x] \ne \frac{d\phi}{d\theta} (\theta) x, $$ 
but rather
$$\frac{d}{d\theta} [\phi(\theta) x] = x\frac{d\phi}{d\theta} (\theta). $$
You get this by differentiating the component functions of $\phi(\theta)x$, namely $\phi(\theta)x_i$, $1\le i \le p$.